# JavaFx TextArea change caret position issue - charactor selected unexpectedly

Tags: javafx, textarea, textfield, caret

I have been trying to set the caret position in TextArea but keep getting a strange issue. I am trying to change the caret position whenever it hits certain value. But keep getting charactor selected for unknow reason.

```
    ta.setText("123456789123456789");
    ta.caretPositionProperty().addListener((observable, oldValue,
            newValue) -> {
                System.out.println("Caret posistion changed: " +
                        ta.getCaretPosition());
                if (((newValue.intValue() + 1) % 3) == 0) {
                    if (newValue.intValue() > oldValue.intValue()) {
                        ta.positionCaret(newValue.intValue() + 1);
                    } else {
                        ta.positionCaret(newValue.intValue() - 1);
                    }
                }
            });
```

when the code is first executed, the TextArea displays "123456789123456789" with the caret position at 0. When I start insert character "A", it displays "A123456789123456789" with the caret position at 1. Then when I continue to insert another character "B", it displays "AB123456789123456789" with the caret position at 3. This is expected. However, the third character "1" is selected unexpectedly. What is the reason for this and is there anyway to avoid to this selecting issue?

Thanks for help!

Comment: This issue is fixed in JRE 1.8.0_51

Answer (score 0):

The anchor is the starting point and the caret is the ending point of selection. When both are equal there is no selection. You say the issue has been fixed in JRE updates. However, a simple way to resolve the bug would be to set the anchor manually equal to the caret. You can do that by listening to a change on the textfield!